# targeted container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

my index.html has 'app' as the div element. When I try to render to this div I get error saying target container is not a DOM element. I even placed the  at the bottom of the body.
My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"
   <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">

</div>
   <script src="index.js"> </script>
</body>
```

App.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              Hello World!!
          </div>
       );
    }
  }
export default App;
```

index.js file

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './App.jsx';

 ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

When I run the above code I get error saying Target container is not a DOM element

Comment: Does the meta tag in the HTML file have a missing closing brace in the actual code? This may cause the div to not be added to the DOM.

Comment: Maybe a typo? `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Comment: I tested both that and the missing </html> tag, neither caused the issue for me. Can't see anything wrong other than those two things.

Comment: Tha didn't help

Comment: are you sure everything looks like it is here cause nothing is wrong with this

Comment: I dont' know why, but when I changed the div id to 'root' it worked for me

Comment: Can you try switch back to previous 'app' id and check again? Maybe you got some issue with hot reloading or something.

Comment: Can confirm the same as @shubhamjohar johar behaviour when I recently have done a react example app